# Insert a native ad in a recyclerview of viewpager fragment

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I am trying to build my 1st app, and want to insert an `admob native ad` in a recyclerview.

I have created the viewpager from android studio's default `tabbed activity`, and have inserted a recyclerview, which is working fine.

Now, from [AdMob Native Advanced Ads in an Android Feed](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#0) I am trying to insert a native ad. 
But, the codelab example uses `Fragment Transaction`. Do I must need to implement that?

It will be helpful for me, if I can implement the complete ad related part in the fragment only (except the initialisation).

Here is my current status of the fragment:

```
public class SunFragment extends Fragment {
  public static final int NUMBER_OF_ADS = 1;
  private AdLoader adLoader;
  private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<UnifiedNativeAd> mNativeAds = new ArrayList<>();

  ArrayList<Object> sunsList;
  Typeface sunfont;
  Double Dlat;
  Double Dlang;

  //to be called by the MainActivity
  public SunFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }


  private static final String KEY_LOCATION_NAME = "location_name";
  public String TAG = "SunFragment";
  public String location;//="No location name found";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      location = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME).toString();
      }
    setRetainInstance(true);
  }
  public List<Object> getRecyclerViewItems() {
    return mRecyclerViewItems;
  }
  private void loadNativeAds() {

    AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(getContext(), getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
    adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
        new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
            // A native ad loaded successfully, check if the ad loader has finished loading
            // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
            mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
            if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
              //insertAdsInMenuItems();
              mRecyclerViewItems.add(3, mNativeAds);
            }
          }
        }).withAdListener(
        new AdListener() {
          @Override
          public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // A native ad failed to load, check if the ad loader has finished loading
            // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
            Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                + " load another.");
            if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
              //insertAdsInMenuItems();
            }
          }
        }).build();

    // Load the Native ads.
    adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());
    if (getArguments() != null) {
      Dlat = getArguments().getDouble("loclat");
      Dlang = getArguments().getDouble("loclang");
    } else {
      Dlat = 0.0;
      Dlang = 0.0;
    }
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sun, container, false);
    RecyclerView rv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
    rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
//    System.out.println("location  " + location);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new SunAdapter(getContext(), sunsList);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
  }


  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle locState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(locState);
    if (location != null) {
      locState.putCharSequence(KEY_LOCATION_NAME, location);
    }
  }
}
```

and the adapter is:

```
public class SunAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private final Context mContext;
  private final ArrayList<Object> mSunsList;
  private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
  private static final int UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;


  public SunAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> sunsList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mSunsList = sunsList;
  }

  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textViewId;
    private TextView textViewSicon;
    private TextView textViewStime;
    private TextView textViewEicon;
    private TextView textViewEtime;
    private TextView ntextViewSicon;
    private TextView ntextViewStime;
    private TextView ntextViewEicon;
    private TextView ntextViewEtime;

    MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      textViewId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
      textViewSicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MSicon);
      textViewStime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MStime);
      textViewEicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MEicon);
      textViewEtime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_MEtime);
      ntextViewSicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NSicon);
      ntextViewStime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NStime);
      ntextViewEicon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NEicon);
      ntextViewEtime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NEtime);
//    mSportsImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sportsImage);
    }
  }


  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return mSunsList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object sunList = mSunsList.get(position);
    if (sunList instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
      return UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
      case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
        View unifiedNativeLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
            viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_unified,
            viewGroup, false);
        return new UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(unifiedNativeLayoutView);
      case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
        // Fall through.
      default:
        View menuItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.card_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView);
    }
  }

  // @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
      case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
        UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mSunsList.get(position);
        populateNativeAdView(nativeAd, ((UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder) holder).getAdView());
        break;
      case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
        // fall through
      default:
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
        SunSession sunSession = (SunSession) mSunsList.get(position);
        myViewHolder.textViewId.setText(sunSession.getId());
        myViewHolder.textViewSicon.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(sunSession.getSicon(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        myViewHolder.textViewStime.setText(sunSession.getStime());
        myViewHolder.textViewEicon.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(sunSession.getEicon(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        myViewHolder.textViewEtime.setText(sunSession.getEtime());
        myViewHolder.ntextViewSicon.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(sunSession.getNSicon(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        myViewHolder.ntextViewStime.setText(sunSession.getNStime());
        myViewHolder.ntextViewEicon.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(sunSession.getNEicon(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        myViewHolder.ntextViewEtime.setText(sunSession.getNEtime());
    }
  }


  private void populateNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd,
                                    UnifiedNativeAdView adView) {
    // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
    ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
    ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAd.getBody());
    ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());

    // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
    // check before trying to display them.
    NativeAd.Image icon = nativeAd.getIcon();

    if (icon == null) {
      adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(icon.getDrawable());
      adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (nativeAd.getPrice() == null) {
      adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAd.getPrice());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStore() == null) {
      adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAd.getStore());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) {
      adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
          .setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
      adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
      adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
      ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
      adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // Assign native ad object to the native view.
    adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
  }
}
```

with this situation, the normal recyclerview is working, but no ad is inserted.
It will be really helpful if somebody shows me how to insert the ad, following the codelab, which probably means, how to implemeant [this section](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#11) in my fragment.

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: nope :( I have satisfied myself with banner

Comment: I noticed in my code if I replace ad_unit_id to test id "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110" - it'is working.